# AlamofireObjectMapper: JSON with Identifier

Tags: swift, alamofire

Is it necessary to write an wrapper-object for AlamofireObjectMapper when the data is encapulated? E.g. if the weather data would be inside a named array "data". What would be the best solution to the mapping?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "conditions": "Partly cloudy",
            "day": "Monday",
            "temperature": 20
        },
        {
            "conditions": "Showers",
            "day": "Tuesday",
            "temperature": 22
        },
        {
            "conditions": "Sunny",
            "day": "Wednesday",
            "temperature": 28
        }
    ]
}

let URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/f583be1121dbc5e9b0381b3017718a70c31054f7/sample_array_json"
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil)
         .responseArray { (response: [Forecast]?, error: ErrorType?) in
            if let response = response {
                for forecast in response {
                    print(forecast.day)
                    print(forecast.temperature)           
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I miss understood the question did you take a look at this documentation? https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper there is an example of configuring the mapper

Comment: Yes - thats where the example comes from. I added the "data:[]"-part. To this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is the most confortable option.

You can have a wrapper-object like:

```
class Forecast: Mappable {

   // MARK: - Attributes

   var conditions: String = ""
   var day: String = ""
   var temperature: NSNumber

   // MARK: - Methods

   init() { }

   required init?(_ map: Map) { }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
       conditions <- map["conditions"]
       day <- map["day"]
       temperature <- map["temperature"]
   }
}
```

Then, to manage request:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL).responseObject({ (response: Response<Forecast, NSError>) -> Void in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print(response.result.value!)
            }
        })
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So looking over the documentaion it looks like the data is specified at the request level as seen in their example here:

```
let URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/d8bb95982be8a11a2308e779bb9a9707ebe42ede/sample_json"
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseObject("data") { (response: 
Response<WeatherResponse, NSError>) in

let weatherResponse = response.result.value

print(weatherResponse?.location)
if let threeDayForecast = weatherResponse?.threeDayForecast {
    for forecast in threeDayForecast {
        print(forecast.day)
        print(forecast.temperature)           
     }
  }
}
```

the key being:

Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseObject("data") { (response:

Comment: they changed their API with AOM 2.0. Do you mean to use .responseObject(<#T##keyPath: String##String#>, completionHandler: <#T##Response<T, NSError> -> Void#>)

Answer (score 0):

You can map response with AnyObject, like example below;

```
    let URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/f583be1121dbc5e9b0381b3017718a70c31054f7/sample_array_json"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseJSON { (response : Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in
        print(response.result.value.debugDescription)
        let arr = response.result.value! as? Array<AnyObject>

        for a in arr! {
            let condition = a["conditions"]
            let day = a["day"]
            print("\(day!!) condition is \(condition!!)")
        }


    }
```

Output :

```
Monday condition is Partly cloudy
Tuesday condition is Showers
Wednesday condition is Sunny
```